# What's the difference between mongoose save and passport-local-mongoose register()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

What's the difference between mongoose `.save()` and passport-local-mongoose `.register()`?

Why does passport-local-mongoose `.register()` require the `username` and `password` only? Can't it get email or address?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `.register()` does: [passport-local-mongoose/blob/main/index.js](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/main/index.js#L222)

1. Create an instance of this in case user isn't already an instance
2. Checks if username is not missing
3. Checks if username is already existing
4. Set the password
5. Save the user with `user.save()`
6. Check if a callback exist if yes return the result in `cb`

You can select which `usernameField` in config:

```js
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: "email" });
```